# How do I rename a superclass's method in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass with the method `run()`.

I make a subclass of the superclass that I would like to have its own `run()` method. But, I want to keep the functionality of the old run method in a method called `oldrun()` on this new object.

How would I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to want to do ... Is there a more specific reason why you want to keep the old version around?

Comment: It seems strange, you inherit the object then alter the API in a potentially confusing way.

Comment: I've since forgotten exactly why I wanted to do this, but I'm guessing that I wanted the new function to expand on the old function and call the old version of the function inside of the new function.

Comment: I found the need to do the same thing when writing a class that renamed an abstract method of its super class (e.g. `do_something_with_x_and_y`) to something which I found clearer in the subclass context (e.g. `do_something_with_width_and_height`). Bumped into the OP's question when searching to see if it was a good idea...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
class Base(object):
    def run(self):
        print("Base is running")

class Derived(Base):
    def run(self):
        print("Derived is running")

    def oldrun(self):
        super().run()
```